# Report with three numbered levels, inline text on

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm new to latex so please forgive me if this question has already been asked/is obvious.

I'm looking to have a document look like:

**1. Chapter**

**1.1 Section**

1.1.1 Paragraph text here in the 'subsection'

The problem being that the subsection pushes the text down to the next line and is bold etc., basically acts as it should (a subsection). Is there a common method of making the subsection act and appear as a paragraph?

My latex document currently looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\chapterstyle{section}
\chapter{something}
\section{blah}
\subsection{}
This is offset on the next line, it should be on the same line.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memoir` document class offers hooks to easily customize the sectional unit headings; in this case, you need to set proper values for `\subsecheadstyle` and `\aftersubsecskip` (a negative value here will give a runin title):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\chapterstyle{section}

\renewcommand\subsecheadstyle{\normalfont}
\setlength\aftersubsecskip{-0.5em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Level Unit}
\section{Second Level Unit}
\subsection{}
This is on the same line.

\end{document}
```

[image]